# Rxjs and React state hooks causing multiple API calls and re-renders

Tags: reactjs, rxjs

I am trying to implement a simple search box in React that makes use of RxJs. The design is simple, and the main logic of how the requests are made to the api is like below:

```
export class SeachService {
  constructor() {
    this.searchTerm = new Subject();
  }

  search(term) {
    this.searchTerm.next(term.value);
  }

  doSearch(term) {
    let promise = api.business.searchByCompany(term);

    return Observable.fromPromise(promise);
  }

  getResults() {
    return this.searchTerm
      .debounceTime(300)
      .distinctUntilChanged()
      .switchMap((term) => (term ? this.doSearch(term) : Observable.of([])))
      .map((response) => {
        return {
          details: response,
          result_hash: Date.now(),
        };
      })
      .distinctUntilChanged((a, b) => a.result_hash === b.result_hash)
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
        return Observable.of([]);
      });
  }
}
```

And I make use of it in the React component as:

```
 useLayoutEffect(() => {
    const subscription = searchService
      .getResults()
      .subscribe((res) => setBusinessResults(res.details));
  });
```

However this results in multiple ajax calls made to the API as if the component re-renders multiple times. When I use a simple `console.log(res.details)` I get the expected behaviour where calls are made only once and throttled accordingly. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Why are you checking distinct calls with a Date.Now()? That will always be different. You should use term instead no?

Answer (score 0):

Here you can handle your multiple API calls. Your API will call only when the user's input has a gap of 2seconds.

```
  /**
   * Handle Timeouts
   */
  timeouts = {
    term_name: null,
  };

  /**
   * Search Term
   *
   * @param {String} name
   */
  searchTerm = name => {
    if (this.timeouts.term_name) {
      clearTimeout(this.timeouts.term_name);
    }

    this.timeouts.term_name = setTimeout(() => {
      this.searchTerm(); // Here you can call api it will trigger only if user has a gap of 2 seconds in his input
    }, 2000);
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the empty dependency array on the useLayoutEffect hook to simulate the component did mount lifecycle. Remember also to unsubscribe from the observable when the component is unmounted to avoid multiple subscriptions when the component is mounted again. The component did unmount lifecycle can be simulated returning a function inside the useLayoutEffect hook:

```
useLayoutEffect(() => {
    const subscription = searchService
      .getResults()
      .subscribe((res) => setBusinessResults(res.details));

    return () => subscription.unsubscribe();
}, []);
```